# clear form field after a submit in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

this my view code

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'cancel' in request.POST:
            return redirect('incident.views.index')
        if 'password' in request.POST:
      registerform = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        registerform = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
                    createprofileform = UserCreateProfileForm(request.POST)
                    if registerform.is_valid() and createprofileform.is_valid():
                        result = registerform.save(commit=False)
                        result.set_password(request.POST['password'])
                        result.save()
                        member.user_id = user.id
                        member.member_id = result.id
                        member.save()
                        member_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=result.id)
                        createprofileform = UserCreateProfileForm(request.POST, instance=member_profile)
                        createprofileform.save()
                        is_member_screen = True
                        member_save_msg = 'New member has been added.'
          return render(request, 'incident/about_me.html',
                               registerform':registerform,
                               'createprofile':createprofileform,
                               'member_save_msg': member_save_msg,
                                  })
```

After every form submit,i want to clear the posted data,actually the form is holding the submitted data.I don't want to redirect the page to some other page as save success message will appear after every save.How to clear the posted data from form on every submit.

Thanks

Comment: Is that only view code you have? You haven't shown us how/what response do you send.

Comment: @Rohan updated the view code,please check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re-init the forms `registerform` and `createprofileform` to empty forms - no POST data, when you want to clear the data.

Sample:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    if 'cancel' in request.POST:
        return redirect('incident.views.index')
    if 'password' in request.POST:
        registerform = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        registerform = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        createprofileform = UserCreateProfileForm(request.POST)
        if registerform.is_valid() and createprofileform.is_valid():
           # your code
           ...
           #reset forms
           registerform = UserRegisterForm()
           createprofileform = UserCreateProfileForm()

   return render(request, 'incident/about_me.html',
                           registerform':registerform,
                           'createprofile':createprofileform,
                           'member_save_msg': member_save_msg,
                              })
```